# Does resizing a photo in paint remove exif data?

Tags: images, resize, windows, ms-paint

I have some images and I want to strip the EXIF data for privacy reasons before I put them up on the website. Is it enough to simply resize them in windows paint? I'm using Windows XP X64.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Hi Vazor. I'm sorry you didn't get an answer to your question, but I don't think you should delete it. I've just edited the tag (it was probably a misunderstanding). Weekends are awfully quiet here, why not give it a change for some more days? The "Have you tried it?" question is partially a common place for us (what have you tried so far?), and also a practical question (did you try it? if yes, why didn't it work?, something like that).

Comment: I want to delete it because I feel the question "Have you tried it?" implies "Why are you so lazy?! Did you even look or try?!" 
(While I could easily go do the research myself, I feel like the question is simple for someone with a little experience so it would be more efficient for them to share. Then everyone would gain, and that's the point of this site, right?)
Anyway with the corrected tag and your explanation I suppose I will let it stay if that is what is wanted. I was under the impression the question was not wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comment 34 of this post: http://photographylife.com/how-to-delete-exif-data a reply (comment 38) mentions that this is a bad method due to re-compression issues - It will remove it, but it's not the best way to remove it.

The article itself mentions how to do it without re-compressing the image in Lightroom/Photoshop.

Comment: 34) OACNVS method
April 27, 2012 at 4:58 am
There is an easier way to remove the EXIF data using any image software (e.g. MS Paint will do it). I will call it the OACNVS method:
Open the image (Ctrl-O)
select all (Ctrl-A)
copy (Ctrl-C)
Open a new blank image (Ctrl-N)
Paste (Ctrl-V)
Save the new image (Ctrl-S)
With this procedure, only the image content is copied, not the EXIF data. For a small low-res photograph I had, the jpeg file size changed from 22 kb to 12 kb.

Comment: 38) Iustin
July 7, 2012 at 6:55 am
However, this is bad method, since it will re-compress the JPEG data, leading to quality loss. The exiftool method (or any other method which only modifies the EXIF metadata) will not alter the actual image contents.